# How to retrive state of subsystem in CL script in as400

Tags: ibm-midrange

How do retrieve state of subsystem through CL script in as400.
I want to check if subsystem is active or not.

Answer (score 1):

There's an API for that.  The specs for "Retrieve Subsystem Information (QWDRSBSD) API" are at:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/apis/qwdrsbsd.htm.

There are several variations of a custom "RTVSBSSTS" command that make use of the API.